# Пунктуация в предложении: "Он стал другим, мой дед — постарел, сгорбился"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

> Он стал другим, мой дед — постарел, сгорбился.

Что поставить, запятую или тире?

Comment: Тире на клавиатуре: alt+151.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант редактирования:

**Он стал другим, мой дед, постарел, сгорбился.**

В этом предложении первое сказуемое является **обобщающим** по отношению к двум другим, которые раскрывают (**поясняют**) его содержание, но **пояснительные отношения лучше здесь не обозначать.**

Можно поставить двоеточие или тире, но это сильные знаки для этого нераспространенного предложения.

А при постановке тире надо еще и сохранять запятую, закрывающую обособленное приложение.  Такое количество знаков нежелательно.

Comment: Почему БСП, разве все глаголы не относятся к одному и тому же подлежащему *он*?

Comment: Это  сказуемые в простом предложении. Они однородны грамматически  (относятся к одному подлежащему), но неоднородны по смыслу.

Answer (score 3):

Есть три варианта, и все три допустимы:

1. Он стал другим, мой дед, постарел, сгорбился.
2. Он стал другим, мой дед, — постарел, сгорбился.
3. Он стал другим, мой дед: постарел, сгорбился.

Если видеть здесь пояснение, то по правилам (см. ниже) больше подходит второй вариант. Обратите внимание на сочетание запятой и тире, где каждый знак поставлен на своем основании.

Но можно увидеть здесь и просто три однородных сказуемых — тогда ставим запятую.

Пояснительные члены предложения обычно выделяются запятыми. Но не всегда.

> 1) При отсутствии пояснительных союзов то есть, именно, а именно и при наличии пояснения выделение происходит обычно с помощью тире, а не запятой.
>
> Разговор шёл один – о погоде; Профессия его была самая мирная – учитель.
>
> 2) Встречается постановка двоеточия при пояснительном члене предложения. Обычно двоеточие ставится для того, чтобы избежать двух тире.
>   ([Пояснительные члены предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html))

Comment: Вы говорите: "Пояснительные члены предложения обычно выделяются запятыми. Но не всегда".   Выделяются, если они одиночные, но у нас же однородный ряд. По вашей ссылке нет таких примеров. Если это ряд с обобщением, то для него характерны тире или двоеточие, но Вы допускаете запятую. Как это можно объяснить и какой вариант Вы считаете лучшим (как бы сами написали)?

Comment: @Sharon, Вы правы, здесь однородный ряд, тогда два подхода возможны: пояснительные члены либо обобщающее слово при однородных членах. Не думаю, что корректно смешивать  оба подхода (у Вас однородные члены поясняют обобщающее слово). Не уверен какой подход вернее. Не встречал в теории объяснений по поводу более одного пояснительного члена. Так что вопросы остаются. Запятую можно оправдать не только наличием пояснения, но и так: здесь просто три однородных сказуемых.

Comment: Я себя обычно не затрудняю подходами. Грамматика однородная, но семантика разная. Если первое слово неопределенное, то далее следует пояснение (обычно это одиночные слова). Если обобщение, то мы имеем обобщающее слово и однородный ряд, его раскрывающий.  Правила можно найти для обоих тем. Но нежелательно называть их однородными, можно просто приравнять к однородным, если это удобно в данном предложении. То есть есть правила, но есть и некоторая свобода действия, определяемая конкретными факторами.